# Adapter Mobile First doesn't get the response

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have problem when my cordova apps try to call the procedure in adapter, the adapter doesn't return the response.
The response of adapter is just like this :

```
errorMsg: "OK"
invocationContext: null
responseHeaders:
cache-control: "no-cache"
connection: "close"
content-type: "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
expires: "0"
pragma: "no-cache"
__proto__: Object
responseText: "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="TEXT/HTML; CHARSET=utf-8"/><title>Error</title></head><body><H2>Error</H2><table summary="Error" border="0" bgcolor="#FEEE7A" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="400"><tr><td><table summary="Error" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1"><tr valign="top" bgcolor="#FBFFDF" align="left"><td><STRONG>Error</STRONG></td></tr><tr valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><td>This page can't be displayed. Contact support for additional information.<br/>The incident ID is: N/A.</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></body></html>"
status: 200
```

I have no idea whats the problem is. Please Help to solve this.

Update:
This is payload that I send into adapter (REST)

```
{
  "id": "xxx",
  "userID": "ANDxxx",
  "firstName": "ANDY",
  "lastName": "JOHNSON",
  .............
}
```

Notes :
- I use mobile first 8.0.0.00-20180504-092633 version
- I think it's intermittent. Because just some data in payload that I sent into adapter that return no response

Comment: This message "This page can't be displayed. Contact support for additional information.<br/>The incident ID is: N/A" is custom. Looks like something in the middle ( between mobile and MFP server) is returning this message.

Comment: Could you explain what "Looks like something in the middle" means?. I mean an example of that? Is possible about the data in the payload that my apps send into adapter?

Comment: MFP server does not return html. The custom html response if not from MFP. Is there a security gateway or something that is returning that custom response. Can you verify if the request is reaching MFP server?

Comment: I got thats message when I debug my apps in below procedure. It can be say that my request is reaching MFP server?


`var request = new WLResourceRequest('/adapters/'+adapters+'/'+procedures, WLResourceRequest.POST,300000);`
`request.addHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip");`
`request.sendFormParameters(formParams).then(`
`function(response) { // -> I got the response from here `
`// success flow, the result can be found in response.responseJSON`
`},function(error) {`
`// the error code and description can be found in error.errorCode and error.errorMsg fields respectively}`

Comment: If the some object in my payload that I request contain word 'AND' it returns no response like that. But, if not contain word 'AND' , my request got the response. Is there a function or procedure in adapter or what else that prevents object that contain word 'AND'?
In local it can be work and return the response, but in mobileApps (Android or iOS) it doesn't return the response

Comment: What is "AND" here? Can you show how the request is with this "AND" keyword? Can you update the question with the request framed?

Comment: @VivinK, I have update my question. It's possible the message is from adapter in my MFP Server? Like javaAdapter?

Comment: I use tomcat for my MFP Server and in the tomcat server configuration set the `maxHttpHeaderSize`, `maxPostSize`, `maxThreads`, `disableUploadTimeout` and `connectionUploadTimeout`. Is the message coming from that server configuration?

Comment: This message "This page can't be displayed. Contact support for additional information.<br/>The incident ID is: N/A." is definitely not from MFP server. If there a webserver in between? Check if the request is reaching the adapter. With some debug lines in the adapter, you can verify it,